# Singing the song of angry men

Tags: discussion, graduation

### Nigh three weeks ago, we made official [our request to exit beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322781/386257).

During this time, efforts have been made to keep attention on the request: @ChrisSunami offered a bounty on the question in order for it to gain more attention, and I have been making edits to it in order to keep it on the first page.

### As of yet, we have received neither "yea" nor "nay".

All we've heard is that *four years ago* the admins started discussing breaking graduation into distinct parts.

**This doesn't help us.** First, because the discussion is four years old, and it is not clear what progress has been made on it. Second, and more important, it does not answer when or whether we can have *any* of the parts of graduation. This is further frustrating since all features of graduation except for the graphic design are not custom-per-site, and therefore could be done easily. Nonetheless, we have been begging for the most minor of those elements (the removal of the 'beta' label) for over a year now, to no avail.

### All in all, we are being ignored.

Which begs the question: **how do we escalate?**

To start, as you can see, I have changed my profile picture to this:

[image]

Please go ahead and join me in doing this, so our desire to graduate is visible everywhere, and to everyone. Let's colour Writing.SE red! (Also, if someone has a smidgeon of experience with graphics, and can make this banner look better, it would be great.)

### What else can we do to attract attention?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without

Comment: I'm following you on the profile pic part. Maybe I'll come up with something even flashier.

Comment: Are we able to answer the post on Meta to try and get attention to it, and see if we can boost its profile? Sorry, not used the official Meta site much, so not sure what constitutes a good answer there, as it feels like I'll just be commenting.

Comment: @CraigSefton if you can answer with further explanation about why we (and maybe other sites) need to graduate already, that's an acceptable answer. If all you do is reiterate what I've already said, it's more of a comment. (All according to prosepraise's link above.)

Answer (score 5):

## Q: What else can we do to attract attention?

### What not to do... maybe...

Probably not escalate this into a protest movement that turns it into a faction vs site admin duality. Because doing that likely won't win you any champions in the SE administration. Contributing to the site at large, being professionally diligent in your use of writing.se, and understanding that it might not be in SE's interest to "graduate" writing.se are probably good places to start.

If you happen to be good at playing politics, then figuring out who the right people to get chummy with are and doing so respectively may one day grant you the ability to say at a con over a glass of beer, "Why isn't Writing.SE out of beta?" To which you might get an adequate response. Or it might doom us all to unprofessional-creepy-writing stalker status if you're not as good as you imagine yourself to be.

It is unlikely that writing.se is being ignored out of hostility. I know how busy I am, and I don't even have an inkling of how many people I ignore on a daily basis that might want my attention. There's probably a multitude. And writing.se might be that non-maliciously-ignored entity to the greater se administration. Let's face it; this is a *programming* help website first.

### What to do?

Keep making the good case in a calm manner that's easy to ingest and easy to say yes to.

Don't fret if we don't get it. The imagined harms to the writing.se site (which you may spend plenty of time on, but don't actually own) are unlikely to affect you, your happiness, or your standing in larger society.

Chill, in the good way. :)

We're helping lots of people as it is. That's the point, right?